# Change behavior of a button from another component

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, popup

I have a custom modal popup with a 'Close' button, with (click)="close()" property. Function close() is only responsible for shutting down the popup. However, in another component where I use this popup, I would like to override this function/change this button's behavior to do something else, besides closing the popup. Is that possible in angular?

Comment: Yes, yes it is.

Comment: I try to match my answers quality to the question's quality. Jokes apart, please provide a [mcve] if you need help, and try by yourself, that's how you learn in the first place .

Comment: No doubts it is

Comment: Lots of ways to accomplish this. You could provide a callback of sorts; so the button click calls a custom function.  You could set some config property on the component, so the button can do different things depending on that config.  Without specifics on what you want to do; it is tough to go into details or guidance.